# Unkown display causing elongated screenshot

Tags: display, graphic-drivers

I'm facing some problems with the display. I had this previously but I cannot exactly remember how I solved it then... Okay here is the thing:
[image: screen]
What have I tired, didn't work this time:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/398903/unknown-display-besides-laptop-built-in-display-old-question-but-with-no-answer
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/362081/two-monitors-when-only-having-one-in-13-10
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/283018/ubuntu-detects-2-monitors-when-i-only-have-one

#### Some important outputs:

**`$ lspci | grep -i vga`**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)
```

**`$ ls /sys/class/drm`**

```
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-LVDS-1  card0-VGA-1  card1  card1-HDMI-A-2  card1-VGA-2  renderD128  renderD129  version
```

**`$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'`**

```
VGA-0
LVDS-1-1
```

**`$ xrandr -q`**

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   1600x900      59.82  
   1400x900      59.88  
...
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.64*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
...
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1360x768 (0x47) 84.750MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock  47.72KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock  59.80H
```

**`$ cat /etc/default/grub`**

```
...
GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="-1"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="video=VGA-1:d"
...
```

Here is my *primary* graphic driver info:
[image: driver]

The greeter (login screen) is also affected it would hide if I move the cursor to the elongated / extended screen.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Oh yeah one more thing mirroring the display is the current workaround. But it still affects the login screen if I log-out (not lock-out).

Comment: `xrandr --auto && xrandr --output VGA-0 --off` also works but is not a permanent solution.

Comment: Have you tried adding the xrandr command to the bottom of the .profile file in your home directory so that is applied when you log in? This may not be the most elegant solution but it might work until something better comes along. I am using this method to add additional resolutions for my built in laptop monitor.

Comment: Nope it doesn't help...

Comment: One thing I can try is by creating `xorg.conf` file but I need some reference help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a long time since I posted the question.

#### Workaround

As a workaround up until now I **purged** all the NVIDIA drivers and installed and added `video=VGA-1:d` this the grub file, which seemed to work fine.

#### Possible Solution

Yesterday I had to clean up my system completely. So after a fresh install of elementary OS (from: `elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200603.iso`) not surprisingly I got this:

[image]

[image]

Remember this time my grub file is new and has no modifications. So I upgraded the system `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. Then I installed the Ubuntu drivers with:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

It automatically installed all the necessary drivers (including NVIDIA GeForce driver v390.18)

Rebooted and bingo! It worked like charm.

[image]

[image]

#### Info Outputs

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 525M] (rev a1)

$ ls /sys/class/drm
card0  card0-DP-1  card0-HDMI-A-1  card0-LVDS-1  card0-VGA-1  card1  renderD128  renderD129  version

$ xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }'
LVDS-1-1

$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-1-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.64*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
...
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ cat /etc/default/grub
...
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
...
```

#### Some observations

- Parallelly I had installed Linux Lite 5.0 (Ubuntu base 20.04 & kernel 5.4.x). It did not show any such problems.
- Neither was it seen on Parrot OS (well... it's not Ubuntu based, so probably of less relevance in this context).
- I installed elementary OS on other systems with newer NVIDIA integrated as well as dedicated cards and non of them had this problem.

> So probably Bionic Beaver has some grudge with NVIDIA GeForce 525M. Haha.

Comment: ubuntu-drivers autoinstall do the magic then. I am wondering what this command is doing. Besides it is obvious that is installing drivers. But I would like to know every details.

Comment: Yea, it did the magic. I too am wondering the same but since I do not have an in-depth knowledge I'm sorry I don't know. Here's a pointer which might help: [Autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks similar to the kickstart. Anyway I think I need to make an analysis one day of the autoinstall config for Ubuntu drivers. In this file everything is set, so it should not be a problem. I am wondering can this command be useful if any of us has AMD, NVidia GPU and not only but also the other brand. I need to do the research. Thanks for the clue. Worth to add this thread to fav. Upvoted.

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for the upvote!